# Black background on CCSprite

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm trying to create a sprite from a transparent PNG. If I use the image for a UIImageView, it shows the background as transparent - as it should be. If, however, I use a CCSprite I get a black background. Here's hw I'm creating the sprite:

```
UIImage *fullsizeImg = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[ele imagePath]];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:fullsizeImg.CGImage key:@"blah"];
```

I'm adding the sprite to a CCLayerColor.

Answer (score 2):

The blending of your sprite might be wrong. Try this:

```
sprite.blendFunc = (ccBlendFunc){GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA};
```

Also, why don't you load the image like this:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ImageName"];
```

Comment: I get the same result with the second method and the blendFunc has no effect.

Comment: (+1) "Also, why don't you load the image like this:" ?

Comment: As I said, I get the same effect.